# How to add List and Dictionary to a List as elements

Tags: c#, list

Is there any way to add dictionaries and lists mixed into a list without using `List<Object>`?

```
list.add(someList);
list.add(someDict);
```

Edit: why i need it? That was my first thought too^^. because i receive that kind of objects and i "should" use them. And i need the keys to check for a velue of a specific key.

I guess thats the structure:

```
List<String> list1 = new List<String>();
Dictionary<String,String> dict1= new Dictionary<String,String>();

list.add(list1);
list.add(dict1);
```

EDIT2: **And it has to have AWESOME performance, when iterating!** I was not sure how Object would perform.

Comment: Daniel's answer will allow you to do that but I believe that if you specify why do you want to do that, you can get answers/comments about better approaches since this doesn't look like an ideal one.

Comment: @Gero How do you intend to use this list once you have it? At the moment, this seems a little [X/Y Problem-ish](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341) to me.

Comment: You say you receive them (how?) and you need to use them (why?). But this still doesn't explain why you need to put them in one single list and what you intend to do with that list.

Comment: with a magicNumber i would know where the list elements start and where the dictionary elements start

Comment: @Gero: Ouch... To me it looks like you are doing it completely wrong. Because you didn't tell us what you are trying to achieve we can't tell you how to do it right...

Comment: its not a specific task. I was just interested in a solution if i were "forced" to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use `List<IEnumerable>`. It's up for debate if that is much better though.

Comment: You can also do `List<IEnumerable<T>>` if you ignore the dictionary keys and just put the [`Dictionary.Values`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8bctb9c.aspx) part into the list.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth (1) That's not what the OP was asking. He was asking about putting dictionaries into the list. (2) This only works if the values of the dictionary and the items in the list are of the same type. A lot of assumptions that can't be derived from the question.

Comment: Granted it is not what he was exactly asking, but this sounds like an X/Y question to me so I was fleshing it out with a further option to gain generic support. I forgot to mention sharing the type.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Agreed, X/Y problem it is.

Comment: I already tryed IEnumerable but was hoping for something with better performance (what ever that might be)

Comment: @Gero: The type inside the list has nothing to do with performance. NOT AT ALL.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a list of `IEnumerable`, but *why*?

Answer (score 0):

You can store both lists and dictionaries in another `List<T>` if you specify `T` as a common base that both the `List<T>` and `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, so the following will all store `List<T>` and `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` in one list:

- `List<ICollection>`
- `List<IEnumerable>`
- `List<object>`

By "performance" I assume you mean without needing to cast? To me this is currently nonsensical, your question seems to be a demonstration of an [X/Y Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341) -  you haven't told us what you want to achieve, you've decided how you want to achieve it and are asking something about that.

Personally I'm making the assumption that whatever this is, it is likely the wrong way to do it.